# nHibernate Key Column Attribute Insert=false

Tags: nhibernate

How do i do an insert false on key attribute like the way we do for join

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like not possible. Insert=false exists on properties (and many-to-one's) meaning the property is omitted whenever an object of that type is inserted. Since a key column is always required, you either have to use a generator (like identity) or have to manually insert the key column. Omitting on insert is not an option I guess...